# Wrong faces culled in OpenGL when drawing a rectangular prism

Tags: opengl, 3d, geometry

I'm trying to learn opengl. I did some code for building a rectangular prism. I don't want to draw back faces so I used `glCullFace(GL_BACK)`, `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);`. But I keep getting back faces also when viewing from front and also sometimes when rotating sides are vanishing. Can someone point me in right direction?

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT,GL_LINE); // draw wireframe polygons
glColor3f(0,1,0); // set color green
glCullFace(GL_BACK); // don't draw back faces
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); // don't draw back faces
glTranslatef(-10, 1, 0); // position

     glBegin(GL_QUADS);


     // face 1
     glVertex3f(0,-1,0);
     glVertex3f(0,-1,2);
     glVertex3f(2,-1,2);
     glVertex3f(2,-1,0);

     // face 2
     glVertex3f(2,-1,2);
     glVertex3f(2,-1,0);
     glVertex3f(2,5,0);
     glVertex3f(2,5,2);

     // face 3
     glVertex3f(0,5,0);
     glVertex3f(0,5,2);
     glVertex3f(2,5,2);
     glVertex3f(2,5,0);

     // face 4
     glVertex3f(0,-1,2);
     glVertex3f(2,-1,2);
     glVertex3f(2,5,2);
     glVertex3f(0,5,2);

     // face 5
     glVertex3f(0,-1,2);
     glVertex3f(0,-1,0);
     glVertex3f(0,5,0);
     glVertex3f(0,5,2);

     // face 6
     glVertex3f(0,-1,0);
     glVertex3f(2,-1,0);
     glVertex3f(2,5,0);
     glVertex3f(0,5,0);

     glEnd();
```

Comment: I'm too lazy to check all your vertices right now, but are you considering the winding order for the faces?

Comment: I'm not considering that. How does the order goes? Could you explain?

Answer (score 4):

The winding of faces 1,3,5 & 6 were clockwise in your code, so openGL rendered them the 'wrong' way around. They should have had anti-clockwise winding. OpenGL uses winding to determine which side of a face is a the front(outside facing) and which side is the back (inside facing). OpenGL doesn't know you are drawing a closed box, it treats each quad individually.

To give the correct winding, imagine you are looking at the quad (or triangle) from **outside** of the box you are rendering. You should list the vertices so that they form a 'circle' going anti-clockwise. In your example;

```
 // face 1 (clockwise)
 glVertex3f(0,-1,0);
 glVertex3f(0,-1,2);
 glVertex3f(2,-1,2);
 glVertex3f(2,-1,0);
```

is treated differently than;

```
 // face 1 (anti-clockwise)
 glVertex3f(0,-1,0);
 glVertex3f(2,-1,0);
 glVertex3f(2,-1,2);
 glVertex3f(0,-1,2);
```

even though the same vertices are used, the order is different. Note that vertices 2 & 4 are swapped.

to render your box correctly, your code should be; (I've fixed faces 1,3,5 & 6);

```
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
 // face 1
 glVertex3f(0,-1,0);
 glVertex3f(2,-1,0);
 glVertex3f(2,-1,2);
 glVertex3f(0,-1,2);


 // face 2
 glVertex3f(2,-1,2);
 glVertex3f(2,-1,0);
 glVertex3f(2,5,0);
 glVertex3f(2,5,2);

 // face 3 
 glVertex3f(0,5,0);
 glVertex3f(0,5,2);
 glVertex3f(2,5,2);
 glVertex3f(2,5,0);

 // face 4

 glVertex3f(0,-1,2);
 glVertex3f(2,-1,2);
 glVertex3f(2,5,2);
 glVertex3f(0,5,2);

 // face 5
 glVertex3f(0,-1,2);
 glVertex3f(0,5,2);
 glVertex3f(0,5,0);
 glVertex3f(0,-1,0);

 // face 6
 glVertex3f(0,-1,0);
 glVertex3f(0,5,0);    
 glVertex3f(2,5,0);
 glVertex3f(2,-1,0);

 glEnd();
```

Comment: OpenGL also provides a API call to change the default winding order.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check the winding order of your vertices. You can read more about it here: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml. Maybe try enabling face culling, then setting it to back. Other than that your code looks good.